# lower pecs for chest workout not in gym

Tags: workout-routines, muscle, exercise-technique

can someone create a lower pecs with no go to to gym?Could you give some workouts that someone could do at his home?

Comment: Have you researched this at all on your own?

Comment: Focus on building full pecs by pushups then pushups at decline/incline angles

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do about your lower pecs without gym. Try buying a home gym its both cheap and flexible. The best you can do is try pushups at a decline angle using a aerobic/step up board.  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can do both push-up and dip variations to target the lower part of the pectoral, and you can do both of these exercises at home.

Do push-ups in a incline position to target the lower pecs. Do dips at a slight angle to target the (lower part of the) pecs as well.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Some men carry fat in their lower chest as body fat goes up(this applies to myself). So I notice I lose alot of lower pec definition when I'm bulking. You might fall into the same category.

I like wider grip dips to get that lower contraction. You could set up something like that at home with some chairs.